# How to make an asynchronous function in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, cheerio

I'm using Cheerio each function to parse some URLS and save all the data into MongoDB. my problem is that cheerio each function as synchronous. and I don't know when the parsing is ended to start to do something else. so How to make these functions Asynchronous ?

```
request(URL, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
       var posturl = $('a',this).attr('href');  
     $('article').each(function(i, element){

     parse_url(posturl, i);

    });            

  }
});
```

here is my Parse URL function

```
function parse_url(url, i) {

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

     var title = $('article h1').text();
     var postid = $('article').attr('id').substring(5);
     var image = $('article img').attr('src');
     var description = $('article p strong').text(); 
     var json = { title : title, postid : postid, image : image, decription : description};    

          collection.insert(json,function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {

      }


    });  
  }
});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the [`async-foreach`](https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-sync-async-foreach) package with `npm install async-foreach --save`. In your first request, change your `$('articles').each` method to:

```
var forEach = require('async-foreach').forEach;

request(URL, function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var posturl = $('a',this).attr('href');
    forEach($('article').get(), function(article, index) {
      this.async();
      parse_url(article, index);
    });
  }
});
```

Now you still have to make your `parse_url` function asynchronous as well, because it is currently blocking. To do that in Node, you use `process.nextTick(fn)`, which is the equivalent of the browsers `setTimeout(fn, 0)` but much more efficient.

```
function parse_url(url, i) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var title = $('article h1').text();
        var postid = $('article').attr('id').substring(5);
        var image = $('article img').attr('src');
        var description = $('article p strong').text(); 
        var json = { title : title, postid : postid, image : image, decription : description};    

        collection.insert(json,function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          } else {

          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Hope ths solves your problem!

Comment: I want to show a console log message when everything is done, where I should write that ?

Comment: the `forEach` function takes 3 arguments. 1st is the array to iterate over, 2nd is the function to execute on each item and the last one is the done function, put your console.log in there.

Comment: This is not working ! when I use this.async(); on foreach functions blocks on the first item, and when I delete it the console log not appearing in the right time